# removing empty image tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a website that gathers images and most of the time it successfully gets an image but other times it renders an empty image tag like this `<img src="" />` and the result is a red x

how do i use php to eliminate these empty image tags?

I don't want to eliminate all of the images, just the empty ones

Comment: How do you gather images? How are they outputted? Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: i like how they added a preg_replace tag. are they using regex to gather images in other websites??

Comment: if the scr is generated dynamically then you can check the image and its path, if its missing then you can show a default image in its place. What do you have for code right now?

Answer (score 1):

When outputting images to display using PHP, I always use a conditional statement using the file_exists function.  If the file exists, then display the image.

However if you already have the img string, then do a replace on the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Put this before your empty imgs somewhere in your script
function myCb($buffer)
{
    return str_replace('<img src="" />', '' , $buffer);
}

ob_start('myCb');

// *Your code*...

// Put this after your empty imgs in your script
ob_end_flush();
```

Please note that it's probably not the right way to handle this but this answer your question. I suggest not generating empty imgs at all since it would be x times faster.